# How to rewrite the url in angular

Tags: angular, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am working on one of the angular projects. The client has one requirement.
For Eg.
http://app.test.com : This is the application website.
http://test.com : The is the static website.

The http://app.test.com has some public profile pages which don't require authentication.
For eg. http://app.test.com/public/chetan

Now, the client wants to change the url in angular 6 application that application must be running on http://app.test.com but public profile pages must be shown with http://test.com/public/chetan.

He has given the clue that we have to use reverse proxy.

Please help : Is it doable? How can we do it?

Comment: only update the angular to 6 in package.json file and url become same

Comment: This can be achieve by reverse proxy(https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/) or an .htaccess redirect(https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection).